# Google Analytics 4 API totals increase when filtering data further (page path and medium)

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am querying the Google Analytics 4 API for data regarding Sessions. In a given scenario, I filter the data with the "unifiedPagePathScreen" filter set to "contains blog" (my specific use case).

In another scenario, I use the same filter and add another filter, the "sessionSourceMedium contains organic", in a "andGroup". Basically, I am looking for all sessions going through "blog" and from "organic" medium sources.

The first result appears to be A LOT lower than the second one, even though I am expecting it to be larger (e.g, 709 compared to 29589 for a given period).

How can that be? I would understand smaller discrepancies but my only explanation would be that only "untagged" sessions (aka without a medium) are returned in the first set. However, there is a "not set" medium that returns a HIGHER count than no filter at all!

---- What I tried:

- Sessions alone
- Sessions with the first filter
- Sessions with both filters
- Sessions with the first filter, and with a dimension (results are way higher that way too)